# OpenCV - IplImage/Mat with 1 bit depth for edge maps?

Tags: c++, opencv, iplimage, mat

I'm currently using cvCreateImage with IplImages to store my edge maps in my code. These are generated with a Canny edge detection and the resulting map either has pixels on or off. From these I perform some Hough transformations whose thresholds are set depending on the number of edge pixels in the image to begin with. So I sum the intensity of all the pixels in an image. However, the lowest IplImage type appears to have a depth of 8 bits. Obviously, it's not hard to make the simple changes in the math to account for this, but it seems like an unnecessary step. Is there a built-in way to create an IplImage or Mat with 1 bit depth per pixel? Thank you much!

Comment: The short answer: No.

Comment: Haha ok, well if that's really the answer, don't hesitate to actually put it up as an answer to the question. Any specific reason why it's not there? If so, I'm sure people would like to see that in the answer too. Thanks!

Comment: one simple reason that comes to mind is it would be tricky to define mathematical operators in a useful way.  I suppose someone figured the memory benefit when using masks wasn't worth making a subclass of cv::Mat with counterintuitive implementations of a bunch of functions.  Also, you might want to use the countNonZero function instead of changing your math?

Comment: "Packing" the information of 8 pixel in the 8 bits of one byte would make implementation pretty tricky, and in general very slow given the architecture in which program are run. If memory is not an issue, don't worry too much about that. Also, be aware that the new image type for opencv is cv::Mat, if you are learning opencv now is worth to use the new interface http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#mat-mat

Comment: Great information, thank you. If one of you (or even someone else) would like to compile this information in a clean answer below, I'd be happy to accept it.